# Разное выполнение функции через button и input

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите что не так, при инициализации функции на input все работает, а вот через button нет, функция выполняется и сразу же "все пропадает"

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form>
      <fieldset class="list" id="list"></fieldset>
      <button id="btn">addStr</button>
      <input type="button" id="pluss" value="+"> 
     </form>
     <script >
      
      function sum () {
       let strUser = document.createElement('div');
       strUser.className = "strUser";
       strUser.innerHTML = 
       '<input type="text" id="name"><input type="number" id="power"><input type="number" id="time"><input type="number" id="intake">';
       list.appendChild(strUser)
      }
    
      document.getElementById("btn").onclick = sum;
      document.getElementById("pluss").onclick = sum;
    
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дефолтное певедение тега `button` равносильно `input` с типом `submit`. Поэтому при нажатии происходит отправка формы. Соответственно надо предотвращать такое дефолтное поведение, если нужно. А можно сделать так:

```
<button type=button>Submit</button>
```

Зависит от того, какое поведение вам нужно